# Include element images in documenteation

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to add element images in my documentation with Sparx Enterprise Architect. I found one tip that said to add Element Image in the Elements Note, however you can only use images from the Image Assets (v 13). Isn't there any way to add the image of an element to documentation?

Thank you for any help!

Robert

Comment: create a linked document and put your images there, this is all i can come up with

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll go with this solution!

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to do that ..
Add everything under a package 
then right click->select documentation->only diagram

Comment: well, I want to add the element images in my current documentation generated with a master doc, templates and fragments.